# Wix CustomAction C# Input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: c#, wix

I am trying to implement a custom action for .msi file. What I want to do is give a msi file following command:

```
msiexec /i somefile.msi /l*v output.txt IPADDRESS="127.0.0.1" PORT="9999"
```

Based on the above command I want to create a file with following content

```
{
 "ip":"127.0.0.1",
 "port" : "9999"
}
```

Now I have implement the following code that is supposed to work in the above scenario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace SetupCA
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult WriteFileToDisk(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin WriteFileToDisk");

            string ipAddress = session["IPADDRESS"];
            string port = session["PORT"];
            string temp = @"
            {
            ""ip"" : ""{0}"" ,
            ""port"" : ""{1}""
            }";
            string config = string.Format(temp, ipAddress, port);
            session.Log("Config Generated was " + config);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\lpa.config", config);            
            session.Log("Ending WriteFileToDisk");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

When running the command I wrote earlier, I get following error in output.txt.

```
Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at SetupCA.CustomActions.WriteFileToDisk(Session session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: The code I wrote is compiled into DLL and is called in Wix Custom Action. Based on the parameter I gave, error was written in log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape `{` and `}` in input string. To do so, you need to add extra `{` and `}`:

```
string temp = @"
{{
    ""ip"" : ""{0}"" ,
    ""port"" : ""{1}""
}}";
```